# Remove only anchor tag from string

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, sanitize

In controller:

```
str= "Employee <b><a href=http://xyz.localhost.in:3000/admin/company>Uday Das</a></b> has applied for leave."
```

I want to remove anchor tag from above string like `Employee <b>Uday Das</b> has applied for leave.`,

I used this code:

```
ActionView::Base.full_sanitizer.sanitize(str)
```

But it removes all the html tags from the string, as a result i am getting `Employee Uday Das has applied for leave.`.

**NOTE:** I am getting strings which is dynamic, anchor tag position is not fixed, it could be anywhere in the string.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `nokogiri` gem.

Something like:

```
require 'nokogiri'
doc = Nokogiri::HTML str
node = doc.at("a")
node.replace(node.text)

puts puts doc.inner_html
# <html><body><p>Employee <b>Uday Das</b> has applied for leave.</p></body></html>
```

or to match your exact output:

```
puts doc.at("p").inner_html
# Employee <b>Uday Das</b> has applied for leave.
```

Answer (score 2):

I got a simple solution:

```
include ActionView::Helpers::SanitizeHelper
sanitize(str, :tags=>["b"])
```

Answer (score 0):

For links, you can use `strip_links` method from `ActionView::Helpers::SanitizeHelper`

```
strip_links('<a href="http://www.rubyonrails.org">Ruby on Rails</a>')
# => Ruby on Rails

strip_links('Please e-mail me at <a href="mailto:me@email.com">me@email.com</a>.')
# => Please e-mail me at me@email.com.

strip_links('Blog: <a href="http://www.myblog.com/" class="nav" target=\"_blank\">Visit</a>.')
# => Blog: Visit.

strip_links('<<a href="https://example.org">malformed & link</a>')
# => <malformed & link
```